# How to detect if view's parent activity is being destroyed

Tags: android, view, callback, android-activity

I want to do some cleanup in a view when the activity is being destroyed. Is there any way to get a callback in the View when the activity is being destroyed? I tried using `onDetachedFromWindow`, but I'm not sure whether it is correct thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the understanding that onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called, you can just callback into your view in the activities onDestroy method.

Edit in response to comment:
You can get any view by giving it an id in the layout and calling findViewById.  Here's an example:

Layout.xml (only showing the bare minimum)

```
<LinearLayout>
  <com.example.superwidget.DropDownTouchEnabledListView
    android:id="@+id/special_list_view" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity.java (again, bare minimal and assuming proper imports)

```
@Override
void onDestroy() {
    DownTouchEnabledListView v = (DownTouchEnabledListView)findViewById(R.id.special_list_view);
    v.doCallback(with, parameters);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on this. My custom view class is part of a separate package and this view is defined in the layout xml. So invoking something on view from activity class is not feasible.

Comment: "So invoking something on view from activity class is not feasible." Sure it is. Call `findViewById()`, get the widget, cast it to the appropriate class, and call a method on it. That being said, `onDetachedFromWindow()` seems like a reasonable choice to me.

Comment: @CommonsWare you comment faster than I can edit. :) BTW, thanks for all the work you do. Your books/code/answers have been invaluable to me.

Comment: @CommonWare: I am writing a library which has custom views, on the contrary to writing an android app. So I have no control over the Activity class code.

Comment: @bhups: In that case, stick with `onDetachedFromWindow()`, unless it causes problems.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get a callback without having to overload the `View.onDetachedFromWindow()` method, you may use the [`View.addOnAttachStateChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#addOnAttachStateChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnAttachStateChangeListener%29) method, which takes a callback listener as a single parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Since `View` contains `Context`, I use `LocalBroadcastManager` for this. So far, I haven't encountered any issues.

The `View` is listening to `destroy event filter`. The `Activity` then just need to broadcast `destroy event`.

```
// On View `setup` function
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(receiver, filter)

// On Activity
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
}
```

Don't forget to unregister the `event filter` once the destroy event is triggered.

```
presenter.destroy() // Your clean-up code here
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver)
```

---

You can find more detail about `LocalBroadcastManager` here:

- [Blog post](https://android.jlelse.eu/local-broadcast-less-overhead-and-secure-in-android-cfa343bb05be)
- [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager)